# Button-checkbox HTML

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!
У меня есть 'button' а у него есть border-radius = 5px (на самом деле это'checkbox')
Это что то на подобии аккордеона у меня есть, написанное полностью на CSS
И когда я нажимаю на него то открывается поле с текстом уже с квадратной рамкой,
на следующий скринах постараюсь показать:
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzamy.png
```

Можно ли как то сделать так что бы при его открытии только нижний 'бордер-радиус' делался
квадратным и исчезала тень, и когда закрываю то что бы все обратно появилось, заранее спасибо!

Вот код:

```css
.cust-accord {}

.accord-li {
  position: relative;
}

.accord-li>input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.accord-toggle {
  max-height: 2500px;
  -webkit-transition: 4s;
  -o-transition: 4s;
  transition: 4s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.accord-btn::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accord-toggle {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.accord-btn {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -0-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 50px;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(209, 205, 205);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.accord-btn::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  transition: .3s;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("arrow.svg");
}

.accord-li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.accord-toggle-inner {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="accord-li">
  <input id="accord-2" type="checkbox" name="cust-accord">
  <label class="accord-btn" for="accord-2">Aktualizacja 29.03.2021</label>
  <div class="accord-toggle">
    <div class="accord-toggle-inner">
      <p>Następujące strony zostały dodane do menu "Moje strony":</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Moja pierwsza strona fanowska</li>
        <li>Moja pierwsza interaktywna strona WWW</li>
        <li>No to jesteśmy w DOM-u</li>
        <li>Style dla wybranych</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись `border-radius: 3px;` является сокращением от:

```
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
```

Соответственно, вам нужно отдельно указать `0` для bottom.

А тень удаляется через `box-shadow: none;`

* Также добавил кнопке `transition: 0.3s;` для плавного изменения.

```css
.cust-accord {}

.accord-li {
  position: relative;
}

.accord-li>input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.accord-toggle {
  max-height: 2500px;
  -webkit-transition: 4s;
  -o-transition: 4s;
  transition: 4s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.accord-btn::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/* ▼▼▼ */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .accord-btn {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
/* ▲▲▲ */

.accord-toggle {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.accord-btn {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -0-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  min-height: 50px;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(209, 205, 205);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.accord-btn::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  transition: .3s;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("arrow.svg");
}

.accord-li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.accord-toggle-inner {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="accord-li">
  <input id="accord-2" type="checkbox" name="cust-accord">
  <label class="accord-btn" for="accord-2">Aktualizacja 29.03.2021</label>
  <div class="accord-toggle">
    <div class="accord-toggle-inner">
      <p>Następujące strony zostały dodane do menu "Moje strony":</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Moja pierwsza strona fanowska</li>
        <li>Moja pierwsza interaktywna strona WWW</li>
        <li>No to jesteśmy w DOM-u</li>
        <li>Style dla wybranych</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что я и хотел!